# Reading and writing to files in command line

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am trying to read from one txt file which is written in six line blocks.

```
SERVICE_NAME: 11178688
DISPLAY_NAME: 11178688
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS  
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED 
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0

SERVICE_NAME: 11572138
DISPLAY_NAME: 11572138
        TYPE               : 10  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS  
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED 
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 0  (0x0)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

Is there a way that I can use cmd to scan these files and read the first line of each block, take the integer from it and write that to a new file?

Comment: which Integer ?

Comment: If you don't need all of the output from `SC Query` then there may be a way of just outputting what you wanted in the first place. What was the entered sc.exe command you used to get your output?

Answer (score 0):

You can, although I'd suggest that as soon as things get more complicated, you should switch to another language. PowerShell is quite powerful for text parsing, despite its object-based nature, for example.

I'm assuming you want the `SERVICE_NAME` part here, if not, just adjust the relevant strings below.

First we reduce the input to only the lines we need:

```
findstr SERVICE_NAME < foo.txt
```

Then we iterate over those, and retain the number:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=2" %%A in ('findstr SERVICE_NAME ^< foo.txt') do (
  set "Number=%%A"
  echo Integer: !Number!
)
```

To write that to a new file, simply redirect the output:

```
@echo off
(for /f "tokens=2" %%A in ('findstr SERVICE_NAME ^< foo.txt') do (
  echo %%A
)) > bar.txt
```

Comment: Note: while `"delims=: "` is technically correct, it probably rises wrong expectations: There are no "two character delimters like `<Colon><Space>`, but both of `:` and ` ` are considered as "one-Char-delimiters" (just using the standard delimiters would be sufficient in this case)

Comment: Good point; I started with `delims=:`, which obviously won't remove the space in front of the number, and then added it as a second delimiter, not noticing that I could have gone with the default all along :-)

Comment: Another point: If they end up wanting a number from another line, say, `TYPE`, then the `delims=: ` would be relevant again, as it ensures that you can just change the search string to any of the words in the file that appears at the start of a line.

Comment: Then `findstr /b` would be helpful.

Comment: ...in my interpretation, the white-spaces seem to be optional, where the colons seem to denote actual delimiters, so `findstr /R /C:"^ *SERVER_NAME *: *"` and `"tokens=" delims=: "` seem to be the most reliable options for me...